# DidSelectRowAtIndexPath SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I have created a table and a search bar controller with it. I have used a structure to create table contents. I just want to store the data in the selected cell in a variable. I am a new iOS developer.please help :) TIA

```
//my struct

import Foundation    
struct areas 
    {
        let name : String
    }

// table contents

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

      var place :areas

        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{

            place = filteredareas[indexPath.row]
        }

        else{

            place = places[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = place.name
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }
```

How to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to know the contents of cell clicked?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/ read this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try that;

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var place: areas
        place = filteredareas[indexPath.row]
        // do with place whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.  Providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a tableviewcell the tableviewdelegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called,the method gives you indexPath so that you can access row from your array as follows:

```
     var place: areas


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    place = filteredareas[indexPath.row]
}
```

so every time you click tableview cell the above delegate method will be called & appropriate variable will be stored in place according to indexPath.row